# What i'm missing? On this code

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to open and close panel. Using this..

```
$('.closed').click(function(){

    $('.social_bar').animate({right: "20px"},800);
    $(this).removeClass('closed');
    $(this).addClass('opened');

});

$('.opened').click(function(){

    $('.social_bar').animate({right: '-20px'},800);
    $(this).removeClass('opened');
    $(this).addClass('closed');

  });
```

But not understand what i'm doing wrong..
Logically this should be work..

Comment: Adding  `click` listener before changing the class is a bad idea, add it after class is changed!

Comment: what happened to this? add/remove class not working or what?

Comment: What's the initial class assigned to your elements, `closed`, or `opened`?

Comment: I want to on click this panel 
put forward on right 20px, and after on click panel go back.

Comment: panel is positional = fixed

Comment: the problem is that it works once.. In one direction, to the left..

Comment: this classes (opened and close), do not have styles..

Comment: you have answers below. do not read only the comments :) and next time share all your relevant code ( html css )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code binds the `click` event to the elements which are present in the DOM when this JavaScript is run.

Since you're assigning the class `opened` and `closed` dynamically on click, you need to use `.on` to bind appropriate events on elements.

Try the following code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.closed', function(){

    $('.social_bar').animate({right: "20px"},800);
    $(this).removeClass('closed');
    $(this).addClass('opened');

});

$(document).on('click', '.opened', function(){

    $('.social_bar').animate({right: '-20px'},800);
    $(this).removeClass('opened');
    $(this).addClass('closed');

});
```

Comment: It exactly what i'm need! Thanks Man!)

Answer (score 2):

You're changing the classes during runtime, yet you only attach the events on load. To make the event handlers react to the class changes you need to delegate them, like this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.closed', function(){
  $('.social_bar').animate({ right: "20px" }, 800);
  $(this).toggleClass('opened closed');
}).on('click', '.opened', function() {
  $('.social_bar').animate({ right: '-20px' }, 800);
  $(this).toggleClass('opened closed');
});
```

```css
.social_bar {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="closed">click</button>
<div class="social_bar">

</div>
```

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Better make a variable which will tell if the panel is opened or closed.

```
var pressed = false;
function show = {...};//here you can provide addClass and removeClass and don't forget to set pressed = true;



function hide = {...};//the same here + pressed = false;
$(your target).on("click", function(){
   if(!pressed){ //if not pressed then show
    show(); 
   } else {
    hide();
   };
});
```

Comment: In function show() and hide() you can provide animate function. :)

Comment: it's good advice, can you show some example it was useful for everybody)

Comment: I showed only good example of structure, in my opinion. It's good to structurise your code with functions. For example: function show() { $(target).animate(params); pressed = false };

Comment: Hope you understood xD